# You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, syntax, line

Hi im running into this error and i just cant seem to see the problem so any ideas, a fresh set of eyes might help.

Full Error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc='ittititi', price='22', img='img.png'' at line 1

```
    <?php
// Include MySQL class
require_once('../inc/mysql.php');
// Include database connection
require_once('../inc/global.inc.php');
// Include functions
require_once('../inc/functions.inc.php');
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
<?php

// try to create a new record from the submission
$genre = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['genre']);
$title =  mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['title']);
$desc =  mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['desc']);
$price =  mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['price']);
$img= mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['img']);

if (!empty($genre) && !empty($title) && !empty($desc) && !empty($price)  && !empty($img)) {

  // here we define the SQL command
  $query = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE title='$title'";

  // submit the query to the database
  $res=mysql_query($query);

  // make sure it worked!
  if (!$res) {
    mysql_error();
    exit;
  }

  // find out how many records we got
  $num = mysql_numrows($res);
  if ($num>0) {
    echo "<h3>That book title is already taken</h3>\n";
    exit;
  }

  // Create the record
  $query = "INSERT INTO books SET genre='$genre', title='$title', desc='$desc', price='$price', img='$img'";
  $res = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
  if (! $res) {
    echo mysql_error();
    exit;
  } else {
    echo "<h3>Book Created</h3>\n";
    echo $_SESSION['title']=$title;
  }
}
?>


<form name="newbook" method="post">
<table border=0>
<tr> 
  <td>Genre:</td>
  <td><input type=text name='genre'></td>
</tr>

<tr> 
  <td>Title:</td>
  <td><input type=text name='title'></td>
</tr>

<tr> 
  <td>Description:</td>
  <td><input type=text name='desc'></td>
</tr>

<tr> 
  <td>Price:</td>
  <td><input type=number name='price'></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
  <td>Image:</td>
  <td><input type=text name='img'></td>
</tr>

    <tr> 
      <td colspan=2>
       <input type=submit value="Create my account">
      </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape [reserved words in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) like `desc` with backticks

```
INSERT INTO books 
SET genre = '$genre', title = '$title', `desc` = '$desc'
                                        ^----^-----------------here
```

Answer (score 1):

desc is reserved keyword for mysql

use it like that

```
     `desc`
```

this must ne your query

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO books SET genre='$genre', title='$title', `desc`='$desc', price='$price', img='$img'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `desc` as a column name; it is a keyword.  If you use it as a column name, you have to quote it.